# Explicit template specialization error

Tags: c++, templates

this one should be pretty easy. I'm playing with templates, but get a compiler error.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T1, class T2>
class Pair
{
    private:
        T1 a;
        T2 b;
    public:
        T1& first();
        T2& second();
        Pair(const T1& aval, const T2& bval) : a(aval), b(bval) {}
};

template <class T1, class T2>
T1& Pair<T1,T2>::first()
{
    return a;
}


template <class T1, class T2>
T2& Pair<T1,T2>::second()
{
    return b;
}

// Explicit Specialization
template <>
class Pair<double, int>
{
    private:
        double a;
        int b;
    public:
        double& first();
        int& second();
        Pair(const double& aval, const int& bval) : a(aval), b(bval) {}
};

template <>
double& Pair<double,int>::first()
{
    return a;
}

template <>
int& Pair<double,int>::second()
{
    return b;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    Pair<int, int> pair(5,6);
    //Pair<double,int> pairSpec(43.2, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

The error looks like this

```
main.cpp:42:27: error: no function template matches function template specialization 'first'
double& Pair<double,int>::first()
                          ^
main.cpp:49:24: error: no function template matches function template specialization 'second'
int& Pair<double,int>::second()
```

Any clue to what could be going wrong?

Comment: The `template<>` there means you're trying to specialize that member function, which isn't a template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need template<> declaration before method declaration.

```
double& Pair<double,int>::first() {
    return a;
}
int& Pair<double,int>::second() {
   return b;
}
```

Should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answer didn't explain why prefix `template<>` is not needed here, i will try to provide that explanaition in my answer.

##### Solution to the Problem

As discussed below, we just need to remove the `template<>` prefix as shown below:

```
//no prefix template<> needed here
inline double& Pair<double,int>::first()
{
    return a;
}

//no prefix template<> needed here
inline int& Pair<double,int>::second()
{
    return b;
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Wf4Kca5cb)

Note that the `inline` keyword is added so that we don't get multiple definition error since usually we implement the templates in header files which are then included in multiple source files.

##### Explanation of the Problem

The reason we don't need the prefix `template<>` is that we're providing an ordinary **out-of-class definition** for the member functions  of a full class template specialization. That is, we're not actually specializing the member functions but instead providing an ordinary(non-template) out of class definition for those member functions.